# Custom build process load error

Tags: .net, tfs, build-process, build-process-template

I used to be able to just double-click a build process XAML file to open/edit it from (TFS) source control.

Now, when loading one of our custom build process templates, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I also have a bunch of errors in the Error Log. The most prominent / severe of which is:

> Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Workspace".
>   Value of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace'. Type mismatch could be due to mixing a file reference to 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll' in project 'vbhost' with a file reference to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll' in project 'vbhost'. If both assemblies are identical, try replacing these references so both references are from the same location.

As well as:

> Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail".
>   Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined.

These are all repeated multiple times for multiple statements and multiple assemblies.

My coworkers are receiving the same errors, all using VS 2013 Pro, but each with different machine configurations (some have VS 2015 CTP installed, others have additional TFS API libraries installed, etc). The errors are consistent across all of the mahines, though.

What is the cause of these errors? The definitions haven't changed in over a year. What could have changed to make our builds not load anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a reference in your XAML to VersionControl.Client from TFS2010.
Look into XAML file for:

```
xmlns:mtbc1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

Comment: What should it be instead?

Comment: If  you're using a TFS2013 build agent then you should remove the version specific:

xmlns:mtbc1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client"